# libvlc: Is there a method to get data buffer before decoding?

Tags: vlc, libvlc

I want to parse mpeg user data and use it for specific purpose.
I've successufully have been able to get decoded frames from libvlc,
using libvlc_video_set_callbacks(). But it is pixel data after "decoding".
I want to get data before decoding, i.e.,  an encoded data buffer.

Is there an API in libvlc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API in libvlc to get access to the raw buffers it reads from input media. Patch welcome!